# Error when Compiling with TexMaker and MikTex

Tags: errors, compiling

It's been nearly 6 months that I use TexMaker and MikTex for typesetting documents. Everthing has so far gone OK until right today, when I complie a document by pressing F1 as usual, an error appreard which said:

**Error : could not start the command : pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test".tex**

The above error comes along with nothing happends in pdf viewer, which means I cannot anything in my PDF page. So anybody please if you know the way to solve this just tell me. Many many thanks to you.

Comment: What operating system? I know people have had trouble with MacOS updates, and that's been answered before.

Comment: Open a command line in the folder of your document. Then type `pdflatex test` and hit enter. What happens?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, I have done what you said but the command line said: **pdflatex test is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**. What is that sir ?

Comment: My system is Window 7-64bit sir (@Chris H),

Comment: This means that Windows can't find pdflatex. Either it needs to be added to your path or reinstalled (which might be easier)

Comment: @(@Chris H), Reinstall TexMaker or MikTex sir ?

Comment: MikTeX. That's what Windows has broken. But maybe TeXmakwr after that.

Comment: (@Chris H), If I wanna add the pdflatex in the path, how would I do it sir. Could you show me the way to  do it. I somehow wanna know it

Comment: There are plenty of detailed instructions for editing your path on Windows. I can't describe it from memory and don't have a windows machine here.

Comment: Ok sir (@Chris H), please if you oneday get the way in your mind, just share it to me cause I would really love to know it. Anyway, by now I'll reinstall them. Thank you so much, sir

Comment: Thank you @Chris H, I have solved my problem by your consults. But I get another one, and I have just posted it in the forum.